# Operation not allowed without an active reactive context

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to build dataset dynamically from the database for R. Below is the code I used for the same but I'm getting error while running it. App is running in shiny.

```
query <- "select * from rdataset" # [col-2]dataset name [col-3]Query
qresult<- dbGetQuery(con,query)
dataset <- reactiveValues()
for (i in 1:nrow(qresult))  {  
   qresult1 <- dbGetQuery(con,qresult[i,3])  # fetching the data from db   
   dataset$qresult[i,2] <- qresult1 #assigning it to dataset so that it can be used later
}
#dataset$MOH<- qresult1 # this line works
```

while running I get following error

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive function.)
```

Comment: This error generally indicates that you are trying to work with something (vector, data.frame etc) that relies in some way on input from the user (ui.r) without putting it in a reactive expression. What part of this is input from ui.r? Can you post the relevant part of the ui file?

Comment: It is the `dataset$qresult` that's triggering this, at least that's what it looks like to me. You can assign to `dataset$foo` outside of reactive code. What you cannot do is read `dataset$foo`. I think in this case, even though you're trying to mutate dataset$qresult, it's counting as a read and a write. This is generally a bad idea anyway, we designed for `dataset$foo <- 1` but not `dataset$foo[1] <- 1` or `dataset$foo$baz <- 1`. Even if that worked, I'm not sure if it would trigger reactivity.

Comment: What I would do instead is build up `qresult` in a plain old variable, and then assign it to `dataset` after it's done.

Comment: Issue is with dataset$qresult[i,2] <- qresult1, there is no error if I change to dataset$MOH1 <- qresult1 & dataset$MOH2 <- qresult1. Here I have to statically declare MOH1 and MOH2. What I intend to do is dynamically get those value from DB. I'm not sure if what I'm doing is valid or not :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have same error in Shiny

**erroneous sample**:

```
beta_reactive <- reactive({input$beta})
beta_coeff <- beta_reactive()

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({...})
```

**Solution**:

```
beta_reactive <- reactive({input$beta})
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    ...
    beta_coeff <- beta_reactive()    
    ...
})
```

Reactive content appears to be a function renderPlot(). 
May be it is reactive because it interacts with output..